# "Watch" long array from Julia REPL?

Tags: debugging, julia, watch

Suppose I have a long array.

```
> using MakieGallery
> size(database)
(210,)
```

If I do

```
> [d.title for d=database]
```

it will print it truncated, and if I `show` it, it will print it into a mess:

```
> show([d.title for d=database])
```

I don't know how, but probably I could print values into a column and it would scroll my console far up.

All this is bad. Is it possible to do some sort of simple "watch" of a variable? I.e. open some small widget in separate window with a list control, diplaying an array, which I could scroll as needed?

Answer (score 1):

Internally Julia uses `Base.show` to display the values in the REPL, you can simply extend this function in any way you like (this example is just a really simple implementation to print every element of array in a new line and you probably shouldn't use it):

```
Base.show(io::IO, ::MIME"text/plain", x::Array) = x .|> println
```

You can then go on and add your function to `.julia/config/startup.jl` to load this every time you start the REPL. Just make sure to have a really solid implementation to handle various edge cases where it might not function properly.

Answer (score 0):

Pluto.jl has a very nice viewer for tabular data (including arrays). It truncats the output per default, but offers a button to show more.

Furthermore, the view automatically updates when you change the data in another cell.